# Performant and Elegant Dispatching on Type for Scripting Language Implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am working in the implementation of a scripting system where values are passed around as `void*` and an enum indicating the type.

```cpp
enum class ValueType
{
    Bool,
    Float,
    Int,
    // many more types...
};
```

I need a workflow for implementing APIs like the following. These APIs must be as performant as possible (switch statement rather than virtual call).

```cpp
void Print(ValueType type, void* value);
bool Equals(ValueType type, void* value1, void* value2);
// etc...
```

I would settle for the kludgy solution I have right now, but it is extra cumbersome given that I have to produce specific sets of APIs for different subsystems. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Current solution (lambdas and `auto` are not allowed in the code base I'm working in, but I'd still be interested in seeing solutions that use those features)

```cpp
// Per-type implementations
template <typename T>
class SubsystemFunctions
{
public:
    void Print(void* value)
    {
        std::cout << *static_cast<T*>(value) << std::endl;
    }

    bool Equals(void* value1, void* value2)
    {
        return *static_cast<T*>(value1) == *static_cast<T*>(value2);
    }
};

// API and gory dispatching details
class SubsystemAPI
{
public:
    static void Print(ValueType type, void* value)
    {
        DispatchOnType(type, PrintDispatcher(), value);
    }

    static bool Equals(ValueType type, void* value1, void* value2)
    {
        bool result;
        DispatchOnType(type, EqualsDispatcher(), value1, value2, &result);
        return result;
    }

private:
    struct PrintDispatcher
    {
        template <typename FunctionsT>
        void operator()(FunctionsT&& functions, void* value)
        {
            functions.Print(value);
        }
    };

    struct EqualsDispatcher
    {
        template <typename FunctionsT>
        void operator()(FunctionsT&& functions, void* value1, void* value2, bool* result)
        {
            *result = functions.Equals(value1, value2);
        }
    };

private:
    template <typename DispatcherT, typename... ArgsT>
    static void DispatchOnType(ValueType type, DispatcherT&& dispatcher, ArgsT&&... args)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case ValueType::Bool:
            dispatcher(SubsystemFunctions<bool>(), std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
            break;
        case ValueType::Float:
            dispatcher(SubsystemFunctions<float>(), std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
            break;
        case ValueType::Int:
            dispatcher(SubsystemFunctions<int>(), std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
            break;
        // etc...
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It sounds to me like using a `std::variant` of the types you want to support and using the visitor pattern (via `std::vist`) would be a good way to handle the problem.

Comment: I don't understand where the scripting language gets involved here. Do you want the scripting language to have functions that can take values of a specific type, or are you talking about the C++ implementation of something based on the values' types? And if it's the latter, *what* are you implementing?

Comment: @NathanOliver interesting idea. In my case where I have to work with an existing `void*` enum pair, I suppose I could repurpose `DispatchOnType` to populate a `variant<bool*, float*, int*, ...>` and then call `visit`. I don't think that cuts down on any boilerplate for me though. And I'm still constrained from using lambdas and `if constexpr`

Comment: @NicolBolas I mention that this C++ code is part of a 'scripting language implementation' to provide some context and explain why I would need to do something like this. For example: Imagine I have an expression in my scripting language `a == b`. My C++ code has a `ValueType` enum and a pair of`void*`, and it needs to determine the result of this expression. In the code provided, it would do this by calling `SubsystemAPI::Equals`

Comment: @yxrkt: "*My C++ code has a `ValueType` enum and a pair of `void*`,*" Wouldn't your code need *two* `ValueType`s, since you could compare different types of objects? It's customary in scripting languages to be able to compare strings containing numbers and actual numbers. My point is why is it that you're dealing in `void*`s at this point in your code? You should be dealing in pairings of the data value and the type of that data.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is true for most scripting languages. In my case, the language is strongly typed and the C++ code is dealing with 'compiled' expressions (an implicit number-to-string conversion expression will have gotten inserted at the compile step). I'm not sure if this disqualifies the language I'm working on as a scripting language. My apologies if it has lead to confusion.